# Not able to insert huge number of (ex: 10000) records with insertMany in monogDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So actually I made a script that inserts more than 10000 records in a document. So what I have done, first I have inserted the 10000 records using insertMany query into my collection. But when I again tried to insert the same number of records, it not gets inserted into my document. Then I have tried for 5000 records, but those records also did not get an insert.

So what is the problem here? Is MongoDB have a limit for records? Please help me with this.

Here is my script:

```
   var resultArr=[];
   var getUID = function () {
     return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
   }
   var date = new Date();    
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + 12);    
           
   for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
       resultObj = {
           "guid" : (getUID() + getUID() + "-" + getUID() + "-4" +  getUID().substr(0, 3) + "-" + getUID()),
            title: 'something'
            }
            resultArr.push(resultObj);
            resultObj={};
        }
    
    db.getCollection('5891847dc654e8e2150b3bff').insertMany(resultArr, function (err, result) {
        print('data saved')
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err)
            db.close()
        };   
     });
```

Comment: Define "did not insert". What does it mean, _exactly_? It just silently fails, or you get some kind of error?

Comment: no there is no error. And I can insert only 100 records with insertMany afterwords.

Comment: You don't You instead use the underlying [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) and even then break it up in batches of 1000. Because the underlying driver is going to do that anyway. If you are loading in 10,000 documents to memory and trying to run an insert, then you have other problems to deal with. Anyhow, unless you show your code we cannot really deal with your problem.

Comment: And even then there is a 16MB BSON limit, and since an operation to "insert" or whatever is actually a "single BSON document" then you have that constraint as well. You need to do things smarter than simply slurping in a load of data and expecting to just throw it at a database.

Comment: Yup, you are right. But i even cannot insert 1000 records after 10000 records have been inserted once.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead:

```
   var async = require('async');

   var resultArr = [];
   var getUID = function () {
     return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
   }
   var date = new Date();    
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + 12);    

   var count = 0;
   async.whilst(
     // Check to see if we continue
     function() { return count < 10000 },
     // The loop function
     function(callback) {
       count++;
       resultArr.push({
         "guid" : (getUID() + getUID() + "-" + getUID() + "-4" +  getUID().substr(0, 3) + "-" + getUID()),
         "title": "something"
       });
       if ( resultArray.length >= 1000 ) {
         db.getCollection('5891847dc654e8e2150b3bff').bulkWrite(
           resultArray.map(function(d) {
             return { "insertOne": { "document": d } }
           }),
           function(err,res) {
             resultArray = [];
             callback(err);
           }
         );
       } else {
         callback()
       }
     },
     // This is on completion or error
     function(err, n) {
       if (err) throw err;
       if ( resultArray.length > 0 ) {
         db.getCollection('5891847dc654e8e2150b3bff').bulkWrite(
           resultArray.map(function(d) { return {
             "insertOne": { "document": d }
           }),
           function(err,res) {
             resultArray = [];
             db.close();
           }
         );
       } else {
         db.close();
       }
     }
   );
```

This splits up the loop with flow control on the inner async calls with [`async.whilst`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst). This gives a `callback` to invoke in order to continue the "loop" so you don't blow up the call stack on node with concurrent running operations.

The actual [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) call is made inside the loop when ever the amount of items in the array reaches 1000, which is the maximum the driver is going to send in one go anyway. You can make it more, but we are saving memory and this is about the "sweet spot".

Using the callback here, we clear the array and invoke the "loop's callback" in order to allow the loop to continue.

Finally when the "loop" is complete you would "typically make check to see if there is anything left unprocessed by the even amounts of 1000. In this case we know it's a round number but I'm leaving it in to show what to do with a real list.

So that part is in the final callback argument to the `async.whilst` which is met when the loop is completed and we can actually then exit.